# Google AdSense reloading?

Tags: website, google-adsense, cookies

Can I reload ads by myself in Google AdSense without full-page-reloading? For example refresh AdSense frame or call some script?

Comment: Probably better for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can i reload ads by myself without
>   full-page-reloading? For example
>   refresh AdSense frame or call some
>   script?

No, you can't.

Comment: I made separate question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9640/google-adsense-cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe and update it's location attribute everytime you want to reload it like this : myIframe.location.src = "myAddPage.html". Not sure it's compliant to AdSense rules though :)

Comment: As i understand such method with iframe do not agree with AdSense's policy;)

Comment: @Edward83 is right. This is not tolerated by Google.